# How to make record just one time in SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

I'm an android developer. Is there a way to put data into SQLiteDatabase only once when the app is running? In my MainActivity, duplicate data accumulates continuously when running the app. I want the data to be added only once when the user launches the app.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val db = MyDatabaseHelper(this)

        db.createRamen(MyData(1))
        db.createRamen(MyData(2))
        db.createRamen(MyData(3))
        db.createRamen(MyData(4))
        ...
    }
...
}
```

[EDIT]

```
class RamenDatabaseHelper(var context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
    companion object {
        private val DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase"
        private val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        private val TABLE_NAME = "MyTable"
    }

    private val KEY_ID = "id"
    private val KEY_NAME = "name"

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE_NAME($KEY_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $KEY_NAME TEXT)"
        db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, old: Int, new: Int) {
        if (old >= new) {
            db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME")
            onCreate(db)
        }
    }
}
```

My data only has "name" key

Comment: Every time you run the app and MainActivity is created, the code inside onCreate() is executed. So what is the problem?

Comment: I only want the data to be generated when the user first launches the app. After that, even if the user turns the app off and on, I do not want to create duplicate data because the data is already created.

Comment: Do you mean you want to write the data only at first time launch?

Comment: This depends on the table structure. Post the code related to the database and the table and clarify.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean (to dtb305). Only at first time launch.

Comment: I added my database open helper class

Comment: whats inside createRamen ()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to execute only once the code that adds the data in the database is to use `SharedPreferences`.
So inside `onCreate()` of `MainActivity` you check `SharedPreferences` if a certain `Boolean` value exists and it is `true`. 
If it does not exist then you add the data to the database and then set the `Boolean` value to `true` in `SharedPreferences`. 
If it exists nothing will happen because this is not the 1st time the app was ran.

```
val sp: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyAppPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
if (!sp.getBoolean("First", false)) {
    <your code here>
    val ed = sp.edit()
    ed.putBoolean("First", true)
    ed.apply()
}
```

Replace the placeholder `<your code here>` with your code that adds the data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add insert statement in onCreate function of RamenDatabaseHelper.

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    val CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE_NAME($KEY_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $KEY_NAME TEXT)"
    db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE)
    val CREATE_TABLE = "INSERT INTO $TABLE_NAME VALUES ($ID_YOU_NEED_TO_INSERT, $NAME)"
    db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE)
}
```

This only executes once.